# Multiline text display with scrolling in winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, window

I have to display multiline messages in any control in C#, which provides me the following 3 possibilities:

1. Scrolling
2. Text cannot be modified
3. Click event

I tried the following options and faced problems:

**Labels:** Label is perfect for me but I couldn't find the scrolling property

**TextBox:** I tried to use textbox, which provided me scrolling but then the user can change the text. And if I set `TextBox.Enable = False`, then the scrollbar cannot be moved an shown the image below:

[image]

Comment: TextBoxes also have a `ReadOnly` property

Comment: @JayV: I set the `ReadOnly = True` but still the user can click it and then the Cursor shows up (I don't want to show Cursor).

Comment: Removing the cursor means no keyboard based navigation - mouse only. Is that what you really want to do given that lots of people prefer or like to navigate using the keyboard? No highlighting or copying of the text from the text box

Comment: @JayV: It's just showing messages on a TouchScreen. I want to show this TextBox as a label (with Scrolling feature). As I said in my post, Label is perfect for me if I could enable Scrolling in it.

Comment: Or, take a look at this SO question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730968/how-to-disable-cursor-in-textbox

Comment: I would go for the [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735(v=vs.85).aspx) control. It's more flexible that the ListBox, supports graphics, different view etc.

Answer (score 0):

On `Textbox` property you can add new lines on `Text` property by clicking the dropdown arrow(see image below) and pressing enter on your keyboard.

[image]

After adding new lines and setting `Textbox.Readonly = false` and setting prefered scroll will solved your problem. Then just adjust textbox to show scroll bar only.

Answer (score 0):

Use a List box if your showing a message. It gives you scrolling, you cannot edit the message, and it's more professional looking. Most of the applications you install and you see the Terms and Agreements. It's usually in a List box.