# How to hide textbox cursor in Windows Forms c#

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, textbox

I need to remove the blinking vertical line indicating the place where text would be inserted, even if I click on the TextBox.

[image: Blinking vertical line]

Note that `textbox` is already `ReadOnly = true` and I **don't want to disable** it.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Blinking Cursor in Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601255/prevent-blinking-cursor-in-textbox)

Comment: The TextBox is ReadOnly and you want to hide the caret. Maybe you need a Label instead. If you add a border style, it looks like a TextBox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable cursor in textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730968/how-to-disable-cursor-in-textbox)

Comment: The caret is only shown when the TextBox has focus. You could try send focus away..     `public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox.Enter += (s,e) => { textBox.Parent.Focus(); };
    }` - Picking where to send it is of course up to you..

Comment: You can set property `Enabled` as `false`

Comment: @Owl that's just what I want to avoid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found two working ways for solving this:

**1. Send textbox focus away**

Sending focus to another component on Form initialization:

```
public Form1(){
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Enter += (s, e) => { textBox1.Parent.Focus(); };
}
```

**2. Create a Label and customize it**

In the label properties, set:

- `BorderStyle = Fixed3D`
- `BackColor = Window`
- `AutoSize = False`

And resize the label in the form design view

Comment: This is just copy cat from TaW's comment above. Should be down voted.