# TextBox allows text entry but does not show caret

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've got a textbox that doesn't want to behave in a Winforms application. It's used to send messages, so it's cleared after enter is pressed using Clear()

After that, Select() is called. Sometimes, however, there is no caret. It IS focused, as it accepts text, but it won't show the caret until it is left and re-entered.

Any ideas?

I've tried using Focus() instead, tried using txb->Text = L"", and they all do it. I even tried calling ShowCaret after each call to Select() but that didn't do it either.

Comment: Maybe using ShowCaret as the opposite of the link here would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131/how-do-i-hide-the-input-caret-in-a-system-windows-forms-textbox

Comment: You clear the text and then call `Select()`. You are selecting what?

Comment: I'm just giving focus to the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce this behaviour you speak about but if Clear is not working you could do

```
textBox.Text = String.Empty;
```

Comment: It's inconsistent, and I'd imagine it's tied to something else somewhere else, I just don't know what/where.